# mat-autocomplete options dropdown does not stick when scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

In my Angular app, I'm using the [autocomplete feature from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete):

[image: angular material autocomplete]

It works fine, except when I scroll the page:

[image: angular material autocomplete scrolling issue]

Basically the dropdown does not stick in its position when scrolling and I can't figure out why.

In the official Material documentation page, it works well by automatically updating the `top` and `left` properties of the element. However, this does not happen in my app.

Comment: I have the same issue and the answer bellow didn't work for me

Answer (score 18):

After doing some research, I've found a solution posted by [omaracrystal](https://github.com/omaracrystal) on [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10079#issuecomment-491620284).

What I needed to do is to:

1) Import the `ScrollingModule` of the [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling)

```js
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    ScrollingModule,
  ],
  // ...
})
export class MyAppModule { }
```

2) Find the outermost div that contains my autocomplete input and apply the `cdkScrollable` directive:

```html
<div cdkScrollable>
  <!-- the autocomplete is located somewhere here, not necessarily as direct child -->
</div>
```

Comment: You need cdkScrollable on element which has scroll.

Comment: for some reason it didn't work for me. It would be helpful to have a stackbliz example

Comment: Pls note 2nd point outermost div.....

Comment: What If my scroll is set by ion-content?
Then how can i use cdkScrollable. It doesn't work with that. Please help.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me without explicitly importing ScollingModule (maybe a submodule of another one?) in Angular 17.2.x.

Answer (score 8):

First of all we need to be able to use autoComplete methods, so we must take this control from the view. Add the id: #autoCompleteInput

```
     <input
        #autoCompleteInput
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        matInput
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        formControlName="country"
        (input)="filterCountries($event.target.value)"
      />
```

In the component:

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger })
  autoComplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Now we have autoComplete as a variable. Next we need a scrolling event:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
}
```

And finally add a function to the component:

```
scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {
    if(this.autoComplete.panelOpen)
      // this.autoComplete.closePanel();
      this.autoComplete.updatePosition();
};
```

Ref: [Origin](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10079#issuecomment-619887760)

Comment: this.scrollEvent? Property 'scrollEvent' does not exist on type 'XComponent'.

Comment: I feel you having XComponent, and you either missed to declare the scrollEvent function or function name mismatch.

Comment: You may share your problem by creating example on stackblitz, I can help you. @RoyerAdames

Comment: I appreciate you Abhishek Kumar. In the end, I got it solved by disabling the scrolling with a div that has 100vh and 100vw

Answer (score 4):

Following solution works for me. Hope this will be a help to someone.

I added **AutocompletePositionModule** module.
Then added directive and used in many places in my project.

**Module file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AutocompletePositionDirective } from './autocomplete-position.directive';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AutocompletePositionDirective
      ],
      exports: [
        AutocompletePositionDirective
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
    
      ]
    })
    export class AutocompletePositionModule { }
```

**Directive file**

```
import { Directive, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutocompletePosition]',
  exportAs : 'appAutocompletePosition'
})
export class AutocompletePositionDirective implements OnDestroy {
  public constructor(
    private readonly matAutocompleteTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger,
  ) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  private scrollEvent = (): void => {
    if (this.matAutocompleteTrigger == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.matAutocompleteTrigger.panelOpen) {
      this.matAutocompleteTrigger.updatePosition();
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" appAutocompletePosition="trigger" />
```

Comment: works but it has the feature of the options not hiding with the rest of the other content when scrolling

Comment: Yes, it may added with updates to angular material. I think I need to update the answer to match with latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

My **mat-autocomplete** is located in **mat-dialog**, importing **ScrollingModule** and adding **cdkScrollable** to my div, didn't seem to help, so I managed to hide the list when scrolling, because when scrolling the list of options isn't really important.

I used:

```
removeAutocompleteFocus() {
    let element = this.document.querySelector('.mat-autocomplete-panel');
    if (element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
  }
```

```
<div (scroll)="removeAutocompleteFocus()"></div>
```

Comment: Property 'document' does not exist on type 'Component'.